# Failure trying to get a pooled connection. java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, multiple-databases

I'm administering a web-based application that is set-up to pull in data from a variety of databases; SQL, Oracle, Mainframe, etc.

I was given credentials to access an Oracle DB, and am establishing a connection through the web-based app server via JDBC. The JDBC connection requires me to provide a Database URL and JDBC driver for the connection. I also built in a SQL statement to pull only the information I needed from the Oracle DB into my web-based app.

Things were running smoothly with this set-up, until just recently. I now receive the following error when trying to establish a connection from my web-based app to the Oracle DB:

```
Failure trying to get a pooled connection to 
[jdbc:oracle:thin:@<SERVER NAME>:1521:cqdb]java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
```

The Oracle DBA I work with is not very helpful in resolving in helping me troubleshoot this issue. Without his help, I really don't even know where to start with troubleshooting.

Any suggestions on where to start? I can provide additional information if needed.

*Additional information. This is what is in my STDOUT file in relation to the error. I can keep digging as well:

```
07:31:08,565  WARN QuartzScheduler_Worker-5 WEB-APP.api.Aggregator:979 - Exception during aggregation. Reason: Failure trying to get a pooled connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER-NAME:1521:cqdb]java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
WEB-APP.tools.GeneralException: Failure trying to get a pooled connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER-NAME:1521:cqdb]java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
    at WEB-APP.api.Aggregator.aggregateAccounts(Aggregator.java:1897)
at WEB-APP.api.Aggregator.execute(Aggregator.java:1222)
at WEB-APP.task.ResourceIdentityScan.execute(ResourceIdentityScan.java:76)
at WEB-APP.api.TaskManager.runSync(TaskManager.java:643)
at WEB-APP.scheduler.JobAdapter.execute(JobAdapter.java:116)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: WEB-APP.connector.ConnectorException: Failure trying to get a pooled connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER-NAME:1521:cqdb]java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
at WEB-APP.connector.JDBCConnector.getConnection(JDBCConnector.java:833)
at WEB-APP.connector.JDBCConnector.iterateObjects(JDBCConnector.java:649)
at WEB-APP.connector.JDBCConnector.iterateObjects(JDBCConnector.java:90)
at WEB-APP.connector.ConnectorProxy.iterateObjects(ConnectorProxy.java:109)
at WEB-APP.api.Aggregator.iterateObjects(Aggregator.java:2673)
at WEB-APP.api.Aggregator.aggregateAccounts(Aggregator.java:1818)
... 6 more
Caused by: WEB-APP.tools.GeneralException: Failure trying to get a pooled connection to [jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER-NAME:1521:cqdb]java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
    at WEB-APP.tools.JdbcUtil.getPooledConnection(JdbcUtil.java:1178)
    at WEB-APP.tools.JdbcUtil.getConnection(JdbcUtil.java:823)
at WEB-APP.connector.JDBCConnector.getConnection(JDBCConnector.java:830)
... 11 more
07:33:03,983 ERROR http-8080-2 WEB-APP.server.Authenticator:229 - WEB-APP.connector.AuthenticationFailedException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, vece
```

**Additional Information:
Oracle JDBC Driver version 14, JRE ver 1.6.0_23-b05. I don't have the Oracle DB version. Awaiting response from our Oracle DBA.

***Additional Information:
This issue was resolved. Our Oracle DBA did something on his end to correct the connection issue. He hasn't explained what he did, yet. Thanks for your help. Sorry for not getting you all the info you needed up front.

Comment: The full stacktrace would be more helpful than only this exception message

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver are you using? Which version of Oracle are you (trying to) connect(ing) to? Which version of JRE are you using? If you Google "Oracle JDBC Protocol violation" you will come across quite a few hits on the Oracle Forums, maybe some help there.